# owncloud "you don't have permission to upload or create files here"

Tags: file-permissions, owncloud

Please someone help me on this I am new to OwnCloud and when I install OwnCloud 8.0.2 I cannot see Upload & New buttons and file & folder listing interfaces see here is my screen, also when I drag and drop some file displaying "you don't have permission to upload or create files here"

permission: /data/ : 770

Thanks!

Comment: Belongs on ServerFault or SuperUser.

Comment: Thanks Paul, checking through server side....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old and in the wrong place but I have run into this before:

> In an OwnCloud server if you change the permissions of an external drive to give r/w access (in my case chgrp www-data) and OwnCloud isn’t updating those permissions you can do this. In your MySQL database find your external storage in oc_storages and make note of the numeric id. Then run this query “Delete from oc_filecache where storage = numeric_id” replacing numeric_id with the one you found in the oc_storages table.

http://blankstechblog.com/2014/09/08/owncloud-quick-tip-for-admins/